# Invoke MethodInfo with void* as a parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

### The problem

Theres an internal method i need to invoke via reflection. It looks like this...

```
internal void SetComponentDataRaw(Entity entity, int typeIndex, void* data, int size)
```

Obtaining the MethodInfo is no problem, but calling it is one. I need to pass a void pointer to it, but such a void pointer can NOT be cast to an object. When i box that pointer, i receive an error later on that tells me it can not unbox it properly.

```
var SetComponentDataRawInfo = typeof(...).GetMethod("SetComponentDataRaw", ...);
var entity = someEntityToPass;
var cmp = new StructToPassToTheMethodAsAPointer();

// My first attempt, not possible to cast
unsafe {
   var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(cmp, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   var adress = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
   var ptr = adress.ToPointer();
   var sizeOfComponent = UnsafeUtility.SizeOf(type);

   var parameters = new [] {entity, cmpType.TypeIndex, (object)ptr, sizeOfComponent}; // (object)ptr not possible
   SetComponentDataRawInfo.Invoke(em, parameters);
   handle.Free();
}


// Second attempt
unsafe {
   var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(cmp, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   var adress = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
   var ptr = adress.ToPointer();
   var sizeOfComponent = UnsafeUtility.SizeOf(type);

   var parameters = new [] {entity, cmpType.TypeIndex, Pointer.Box(ptr, typeof(void*)), sizeOfComponent};
   SetComponentDataRawInfo.Invoke(em, parameters);
   handle.Free();
}
```

The second attempt is able to invoke the method... but i receive the following exception :
`ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Reflection.Pointer' cannot be converted to type 'System.Void*'.`

### The question

How do we invoke a MethodInfo with a pure void* as an parameter ?
Glad for any help on this topic !

Comment: Tried going through `IntPtr` yet? This is the usual type used to represent pointers outside an `unsafe` context.

Comment: what happens if you only pass it directly `prt`? It expects a pointer not an `object` and your `ptr` already **is** a `void*` returned by [`IntPtr.ToPointer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.topointer#System_IntPtr_ToPointer)

Comment: @JeroenMostert So you mean i should pass the IntPtr instead without calling its .ToPointer() ?

Comment: @derHugo Well... thats the problem, i cant pass the void* ptr because it wont fit inside the object[] array which i need to pass to the MethodInfo via invoke.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are possible my hero... i just only passed the IntPtr and i think it works... if you want, you could provide an answer which i accept :)

Comment: Actually, if `cmp` is a struct, then `IntPtr p = (IntPtr) (&cmp)` should do it without bouncing through GC handles and whatnot (it's not going to move around while on the stack). It is possible to do this without invoking `unsafe` code if necessary; that involves `Marshal.StructureToPtr` (but then you have to allocate memory separately).